# count the rows in a table and change the width of a single column ..?

Tags: php, html, css

i need to get the counting of the table rows in order as a column in column "N"
also i need to make the column"N" width looks smaller than others columns
i think i have done everything but this is the only point i couldn't achieved

the output should be as the picture :

[image]

i hope you could help me guys, thank you
**here is my codes :**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  // DataBase connection
  $host     = "localhost";
  $user     = "root";
  $password = "";
  $db       = "worksheet9";

  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

  //verfiy Connection
  if( mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo " Connection Error:" . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $task=$_POST['task'];
    
  // insert sql query 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dolist (task) VALUES ('$task')";
    
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
  // verify query 
    if ($result) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
  }  
?> 
<form method='POST'>
<input type="text" name="task" id="task" required 
        placeholder="add task" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('you must fill the task')"
        oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"> 
<input type="submit"name="submit"value="add task" ><!-- comment -->

</form> 

<table border="1">
  <tr> 
    <th> N </th>
    <th>ID </th> 
    <th>task</th> 
    <th>delete</th><!-- comment -->
    <th>update</th>
  </tr>

<?php
  //  Select sql query 
  $sql    = "SELECT ID,task FROM dolist";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo"<form method ='POST'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='number' readonly name='number' value='" . $rows[''] . "'></td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' readonly name='id' value='" . $rows['ID'] . "'></td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' name='task' value= '" . $rows['task'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='delete' value='x'>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='update' value='update'>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
  }
  
  if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $sql    = "UPDATE dolist SET task='$_POST[task]'WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
    if($result){
      echo "updated";
    } else {
      echo "update faild";
    }
  } 
  //perform only when the user click on Delete
  if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $sql    = "DELETE FROM dolist WHERE ID=$_POST[id]";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
    if($result){
      echo "DELETED";
      }else{
      echo "delete faild";
    }
  }
?>  
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with PHP, but the fact that you're passing user inputted form data directly into a SQL query makes me nervous.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: You should know by hearth, from HTML basics that `<tr>` is not a valid `<form>` descendant. Also learn about `<thead>` and `<tbody>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For row numbering add a counter to your PHP code:

```
$rowNumber = 1;
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo"<form method ='POST'>";
    echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $rowNumber++. "</td>"; 

       // echo other fields...
               
    echo"</tr>";
```

For formatting, give your table an ID (not essential but it makes the CSS styling more specific)

This should then generate HTML like this:

```
<table id="results">
    <tr><th>N</th><th>ID</th><th>task</th><th>Delete</th><th>Update</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>11</td><td>task</td><td>X</td><td>Update</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>12</td><td>task</td><td>X</td><td>Update</td></tr>

</table>
```

Now you can style it with CSS:

```
   /* Border around the table */
   #results {     
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    /* Border around the individual cells */
    #results th, #results td {
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }

    /* Set the width of the first TH. Also sets the width of the res of the column */
    #results th:first-of-type {
        width:1em;
    }
    /* Set the width of the 3rd column (the 'task' column */
    #results th:nth-of-type(3) {
        width:10em;
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Note: you could do this by adding class attributes to the `<th>` elements and styling those. It makes for easier maintenance later.

Use of formatting attributes in HTML tags (like `BORDER="1"`) is considered bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: That's great ! it really works, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JS or PHP to count something **pure CSS** can help you with

- Use [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)
- Use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` table elements
- Use `width: 0%;` for the `td` you want really condensed in width

```css
.tbodyCount {
  counter-reset: rowIndex; 
}

.tbodyCount tr {
  counter-increment: rowIndex;            
}

.tbodyCount td:nth-child(1)::before  {
  width: 0%;     /* Make as smaller as possible */
  content: counter(rowIndex); /* Learn about counters*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>N</th>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbodyCount">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```